# Thousand separated value to integer

Tags: c#

I want to convert a thousand separated value to integer but am getting one exception.

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble("100,100,100");
```

is working fine and getting `d=100100100`

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32("100,100,100");
```

is getting one format exception

> Input string was not in a correct format

Why?

Comment: I hate to say it but I suspect the "Why?" is "Because", I'd suspect it was an arbitrary decision that an integer has no commas or periods.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this:

```
int i = Int32.Parse("100,100,100", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Note that the `Parse` method will throw an exception on an invalid string, so you might also want to check out the `TryParse` method as well:

```
string s = ...;
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i))
{
    // if you are here, you were able to parse the string 
}
```

Comment: Int32.Parse can have a _format-parameter_ too: Int32.Parse("100,100,100", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: The default NumberStyles for Int32.TryParse are NumberStyles.Integer so to add the optional thousands separator, the NumberStyles ought to be (NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands)

Comment: NumberStyles.AllowThousands saved me from pulling my hair out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) is actually calling in your example is [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx).

The `Int32.parse(string)` method only allows three types of input: white space, a sign, and digits.  In the following configuration [ws][sign]digits[ws] (in brackets are optional).

Since your's contained commas, it threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're supposed to specify a string containing a plain integer number (maybe preceded by +/- sign), with no thousands separator. You have to replace the separator befor passing the string to the ToInt32 routine.

Comment: I think the OP has gathered that but is asking why it's that way.

Comment: Edited with added explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have separators, just numbers 0 thru 9, and an optional sign.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx